# issue using setTimeout() more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey guys I am trying to use mutliple setTimeout() like this:

```
setTimeout(function()
{ 
    $('#hoverbox h2').html("...");
    $('#hoverbox p').html("\...");
},0)

setTimeout(function()
{ 
    $('#hoverbox h2').html("..");
    $('#hoverbox p').html("...");
},3500)

setTimeout(function()
{ 
    $('#hoverbox h2').html("...");
    $('#hoverbox p').html("...");
},3500)
```

I just put the `...` I had text in originally... So the issue is when I run this it will start at first one than wait 3500 mili and jump straight to bottom one?

Please let me know how to stop this!

Comment: What did you expect? The second and third both have 3500 ms delays.

Comment: You don't need to have a `setTimeout` function for the first block.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, he may need that depending on context

Comment: If you are using jQuery, why don't you use `.delay()`?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Because `.delay()` only works for animation queues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second and third `setTimeout` runs simultaneously (almost). Either you can put a `7000` delay in third or initialize third inside second `setTimeout`.

```
 setTimeout(function () {
     $('#hoverbox h2').html("...");
     $('#hoverbox p').html("\...");
 }, 0)

 setTimeout(function () {

     $('#hoverbox h2').html("..");
     $('#hoverbox p').html("...");
     setTimeout(function () {

         $('#hoverbox h2').html("...");
         $('#hoverbox p').html("...");
     }, 3500)

 }, 3500)
```